# FATAL ERROR CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION FORMAT() ON STRING

Tags: php, arrays, function, format

Anyone could help me? I have the following fatal error:
uncaught error:
call to a member function format on string on line 89;

the line 89 is

```
    $monday->setISODate($days->format("o"),$days->format("W"));
```

my function is:

```
function dateToWeekPeriod($days)
{
  $monday = new DateTime();
  $monday->setISODate($days->format("o"),$days->format("W"));
  $sunday = clone $monday;
  $sunday->modify("+6 day")->setTime(23,59);

  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
  $period = new DatePeriod($monday, $interval, $sunday);
  return $period;
}
```

my function main is:

```
function main()
{
    $end = new DateTime("now");
    $begin= clone $end;
    $begin->modify('-50 days')->setTime(23,59);
    echo $end->format('Y-m-d'), "\n", $begin->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
    $interval= new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange= new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end->modify("+1 day"));

    $days=array();
    foreach($daterange as $date)
    {
      $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
      array_push($days,$date->format('Y-m-d'));
    }
    echo "-----les dates de l'intervalle sont:-----\n";
    var_dump($days);

    $Week=array();
    $datas=array();
    $Weeks=array();
    $insertAnnee=array();
    $recupAnnee=array();
    $tabRecupAnneeDesc=array();

    foreach($days as $d)
    {
      $week = periodToDayArray(dateToWeekPeriod($d));//les jours de la semaine concernée
      $Week=array_push($Week,$week);
    }
```

I have got a stack trace on this line:

```
$week = periodToDayArray(dateToWeekPeriod($d))
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `array_push($days,$date->format('Y-m-d'));` You can't format something that's already been formatted.

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING. In the title it'e especially outrageous.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, `$days` is a string array.
You pass an element (string) of this array into the `dateToWeekPeriod` function.

```
$monday->setISODate($days->format("o"),$days->format("W"));
$days->format("o") // not possible
```

The easiest way is to keep `$days` on the date.

```
$days=array();
  foreach($daterange as $date)
  {
    array_push($days,$date);
  }
```

Comment: if I made what you say I have got a problem: I have an array of object with three fields (time zone, date, et time zone type).

Comment: I just want date in these three fields.

Comment: So my question is the following how do you push only one field in one array instead of pushing the three?